# Запуск cmd от имени администратора в WPF

Tags: c#, консоль, cmd

нужно чтобы программа выполняла команду в cmd от имени администратора, а именно "sfc /scannow". Пробовал сделать так, но программа не спрашивает о правах админа:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "cmd";
psi.Arguments = @"/k sfc /scannow";
Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: `psi.Verb = "runas";`

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
psi.Verb = "runas";
```

Закреплю для ответа